# Join two columns from two different tables where both the columns have partially similar data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, [A] and [B]. I want to join both tables on the [City] column from table [A] and [Cities renown for] column from table [B].

So the [City] column from table [A] looks like this.

```
+---------------+
|     City      |
+---------------+
| Orlando       |
| New York      |
| Los Angeles   |
+---------------+
```

and the [Cities renown for] column from table [B] looks like this.

```
+----------------------------+
|    [Cities renown for]     |
+----------------------------+
| New York_Status of Liberty |
| Orlando_Disney World       |
| Los Angeles_Hollywood      |
+----------------------------+
```

My tables have about ten thousand rows each and I want to match the columns based on the city names like Orlando = Orlando_Disney World

So I have written my query like this.

```
Select a.[City]
from [A] as a
    inner join [B] as b
        on a.[City] = b.[Cities renown for]   
where a.[City] = b.[Cities renown for]
```

I know I am doing the last two lines wrong but don't know really how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is redundant here, so you can remove it since you are using an `inner join`.

Since `Cities renown for` isn't an exact match, you'll need to get the city *part* from that column.

Something like

```
Select a.[City]
from [A] as a
    inner join [B] as b on
    a.[City] = left(b.[Cities renown for]  ,charindex('_',b.[Cities renown for]  ) - 1)
```

This makes an index on `b.[Cities renown for]` unusable though. This is also based on the sample data where the logic seems to be `City_Renowned for` meaning the city followed by an underscore. In the code above, we use `charindex` to find the location of that underscore, and take everything to the `left` of it.

Or, as [Tab Alleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507566/tab-alleman) pointed out, `LIKE` which may or may not  increase performance. [Here's an article on that](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/).:

```
Select a.[City]
from [A] as a
    inner join [B] as b on
    b.[Cities renown for] like a.[City] + '%'
```

Comment: Why not join on a `LIKE` operator?

Comment: What if there is no underscore? Like Orlando = OrnaldoDisneyWorld

Comment: then use `LIKE` in the bottom query @tkhan17

Comment: Could you please guide me? I am trying to use LIKE but probably having some syntax issue

Comment: If you copy that code from the last part of my post it should work fine according to your post. I'm not sure what error you are getting @tkhan17

Comment: @scsimon it worked. I was doing something silly but now it worked you way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is a database you have control over, I would recommend you changing the structure. If Table A is just a list of cities, the city name should be the primary key. Then, Table 2 should have a `City` column  that's a foreign key to the `TableA.City` column. If Table B is for storing things a city is renown for (and each city can be renown for multiple things), you'd have a separate row for each "item of renownability" (not sure if that's a work). Then, your query would be much simpler.

That being said, if you're unable to change the structure of your database, you could use a simple `LIKE` operator:

```
select TableA.City
from TableA
    inner join TableB on
        TableB.[Cities renown for] like TableA.City + '%'
```

As @scsimon pointed out, you don't need a `WHERE` here. Also, this approach would be able to take use of an indexed `[Cities renown for]` column.

Answer (score 0):

This would likely work, using a `CHARINDEX` to find the "_".

Set this up with a CTE to get the point across.

```
;WITH A (City) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('Orlando'), 
            ('New York'), 
            ('Los Angeles')
    ) AS A (Column1)
),
B ([Cities renown for]) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('New York_Status of Liberty'), 
            ('Orlando_Disney World'), 
            ('Los Angeles_Hollywood')
    ) AS A (Column1)
)

SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.City = LEFT(B.[Cities renown for], CHARINDEX('_', B.[Cities renown for])-1)
```